# How can I use Vite in React 18

Tags: reactjs, vite, solution, react-18

Anyone there who can help me to solve this problem. actually I don't understand **how can I use Vite in React 18**. Because in 2023 we doesn't use create-react-app.

Full solution of using this.

Comment: See https://vitejs.dev/guide/

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Vite's [documentation about scaffolding your first](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project). You can simply do `yarn create vite my-vue-app --template react` which already uses version 18 (or other like `react-ts` template).

There are also [community templates](https://github.com/vitejs/awesome-vite#templates) that might be of your interest.